# Finding min and max value JAVA

Tags: java, max, min

I'm trying to learn some JAVA and currently I'm doing some basic programs and I need to read from file then find MIN and MAX values, but in my code I can find only MAX value and MIN value doesn't work. It just shows the value which I have assigned. Can somebody help me? Here's my code so far.

```
public class uzduotis {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    int[] data = fileReading("skaiciai");

    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(data));

}

// Reads numbers from file
public static int[] fileReading(String failas) {
    int minVal = 0, maxVal = 0;
    try {

        File f = new File(failas);
        Scanner s = new Scanner(f);
        int ctr = 0;
        while (s.hasNextInt()) {
            ctr++;
            s.nextInt();
        }

        int[] arr = new int[ctr];

        Scanner s1 = new Scanner(f);

        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            arr[i] = s1.nextInt();
             maxVal = Math.max(maxVal, arr[i]);
             minVal = Math.min(minVal, arr[i]);
        }

        System.out.println("Largest is " + maxVal);
        System.out.println("Smallest is " + minVal);
        return arr;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Time to learn to debug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably because you set your minVal to 0, so none of your positive integer input is smaller than it.

add `minVal = arr[0];` after you declare your array.

Answer (score 2):

You need this instead:

```
minVal = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
```

Otherwise you will never get a lower number than 0 that you start with.

Answer (score 0):

You've initiated your minVal to 0, an already small number. Changing it to a large number is what you need to do.